# How to select both row_number and count over partition?

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I need to find duplicate record (with master record id and duplicate record ids):

```
select ciid, name from (
select ciid, name, row_number() over (
  partition by related_id, name order by updatedate desc) rn
) where rn = 1;
```

This gives me the master record IDs, but it also includes records without duplicates.

If I use

```
select ciid, name from (
select ciid, name, row_number() over (
  partition by related_id, name order by updatedate desc) rn
) where rn > 1;
```

This gets me all the duplicate records, but not the master record.

I was wishing if I do something like:

```
select ciid, name from (
select ciid, name, row_number()  over (
    partition by related_id, name order by updatedate desc
  ) rn, count(*)  over (
    partition by related_id, name order by updatedate desc
  ) cnt
) where rn = 1 and cnt > 1;
```

But I was worried about the performance, or even is it actually doing what I want.

How do I get the master record only for the ones with duplicates? Please note that `name` is not unique column. Only `ciid` is unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this (because I don't have real data and am too lazy to create some), but it seems something along these lines might work:

```
with has_duplicates as (
  select related_id, name
  from yourtable
  group by related_id, name
  having count (*) > 1
),
with_dupes as (
  select
    y.ccid, y.name,
    row_number() over (partition by y.related_id, y.name order by y.updatedate desc) rn
  from
    yourtable y,
    has_duplicates d
  where
    y.related_id = d.related_id and
    y.name = d.name
)
select
  ccid, name
from with_dupes
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 8):

I ended up using similar query in my question:

```
select ciid, name from (
select ciid, name, row_number()  over (
    partition by related_id, name order by updatedate desc
  ) rn, count(*)  over (
    partition by related_id, name desc
  ) cnt
) where rn = 1 and cnt > 1;
```

Works surprisingly well. The master record is where rn = 1 and duplicates are where rn > 1. Make sure `count(*) over (partition ..)` cannot have `order by` clause.

Comment: Actually, this is the right solution.  My solution performs two scans of the table, whereas you accomplish this with a single scan.  It makes perfect sense now that I see it, and I wish I had come up with this myself

Comment: @texasbruce awesome answer, didn't know you can use count over

Comment: @texasbruce This is a great solution, exactly what I needed. Thanks!!

Comment: +1000 for COUNT(*) **OVER** - You can always teach an old SQL dog new tricks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select ciid, name 
from (
select ciid, name,
dense_rank() over (partition by related_id, name order by updatedate desc) rn
from tablename) t
group by ciid,name
having count(distinct rn) > 1;
```

Edit: To find duplicates, why not just do this.

```
select x.ciid, x.name, x.updatedate
from tablename x join
(
select name, related_id, max(updatedate) as mxdt, count(*)
from tablename
group by name, related_id
having count(*) > 1
) t
on x.updatedate = t.mxdt and x.name = t.name
```

You can do a `group by` with `having` to select only those id's having more than one row with the same row number.

Comment: It returns nothing... Does `distinct rn` work? Seems like rn is different for each row in the partition.

Comment: does the edited part not work? just to find duplicates?

Comment: Finding the duplicate is easy.. but I need to find the master record (the one I will keep) and the master record is the one with the latest `updatedate`

Comment: modified it again as per the comment.

Comment: I realize it's unlikely, but an issue I've had with `max()` in the past is it's POSSIBLE that there are two records with the same update date.  I realize it sounds unlikely, but it's possible.  In these cases, `row_number()` is more iron-clad than `max()` in terms of guaranteeing a single record.  I'm guessing `max` is more efficient, as it's O(n).  Otherwise that's a pretty slick solution.

Comment: @Hambone I agree with you. You can actually have 2 records with same date if you use on update statement (or any update statement without sysdate)